# Junit 5, Mockito, constructor does not initilize values

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, junit5

I am trying to perform simple unit test however I have a bit problematic constructor where Strings are created during injection via @Value. Implementation of component fields and constructor looks like that:

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
private final ObjectMapper mapper;

private final String movieServiceUrl;
private final String recommendationServiceUrl;
private final String reviewServiceUrl;

@Autowired
public MovieCompositeIntegration(
        RestTemplate restTemplate,
        ObjectMapper mapper,

        @Value("${app.movie-service.host}") String movieServiceHost,
        @Value("${app.movie-service.port}") int movieServicePort,

        @Value("${app.recommendation-service.host}") String recommendationServiceHost,
        @Value("${app.recommendation-service.port}") int recommendationServicePort,

        @Value("${app.review-service.host}") String reviewServiceHost,
        @Value("${app.review-service.port}") int reviewServicePort
) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    this.mapper = mapper;

    movieServiceUrl = "http://" + movieServiceHost + ":" + movieServicePort + "/movie/";
    recommendationServiceUrl = "http://" + recommendationServiceHost + ":" + recommendationServicePort + "/recommendation?movieId=";
    reviewServiceUrl = "http://" + reviewServiceHost + ":" + reviewServicePort + "/review?movieId=";
}
```

Firstly I've tought that using mocking properties can be achieved by using @TestPtopertySource annotation, however this cannot be done because those fields are like movieServiceUrl cannot be mocked because they are final. So I've tought that Instead of mocking and using @InjectMocks on MovieCompositeIntegration class it would be better to hard code its constructor like:

```
@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        movieCompositeIntegration = new MovieCompositeIntegration(
                restTemplate,
                mapper,
                "localhost", 7001,
                "localhost", 7001,
                "localhost", 7001
        );

    }
```

With that  logic from constructor should be initialized with this hardcoded values however it will return NPE as result.

```
  @Test
    void getUrl() {
        assertTrue(movieServiceUrl.contains("localhost"), "Acual: " + movieServiceUrl);
    }
```

Will throw:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.geborskimateusz.microservices.composite.movie.services.MovieCompositeIntegrationTest.getUrl(MovieCompositeIntegrationTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

How can I achieve such constructor initialization?

Comment: where are you injecting values to `movieServiceUrl` property ?  can you show complete test class

Comment: I do not inject values directly here, movieServiceUrl is created by String creation of                                                                                                     
             movieServiceUrl = "http://" + movieServiceHost + ":" + movieServicePort + "/movie/";